# Cross site scripting vulnerability resolution

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xss

How to resolve for cross site scripting vulnerability in the below code?

```js
window.location.href = "/Logout/Index/"
```

Can it be reolved using :

```js
window.location.href = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(/Logout/Index/);
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read a bit about [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Comment: That line of code is not vulnerable, there is no need to encode a static string.

Comment: Edit: Logout/Index is the path of .cshtml file.

Comment: then encoding should be in that cshtml, because on the line you've shown it makes no sense